# show current month on the page

Tags: jquery, html

I have the following code but looks like I am still missing something.

https://jsfiddle.net/ww3ez6t1/

```
<div id="YourFieldTitle"></div>
$(document).ready(function(){
  var monthNames = "January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December" ];
  var month = (new Date()).getMonth();
  $("input[title='YourFieldTitle']").val(monthNames[month]);
});
```

Comment: Your `monthNames` array is missing the beginning `[`. Also, `$("input[title='YourFieldTitle']")` won't select anything. Your element has an ID so select it with `$("#YourFieldTitle")`, and since it's a div it has no `value` attribute to use `.val()` with. Use `.text()` or `.html()`. Finally, your fiddle is missing jQuery. Sheesh, what a mess

Comment: Thanks. It worked after I made your suggested code change. Thanks.

Comment: Why downgrade??????? It's frustrating. No matter what I do (add code, add jsfiddle, add details) people still down grade. If you are going to down grade then at least let me know why.

Comment: here is the updated jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/ww3ez6t1/4/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, your JSFiddle isn't configured to use jQuery. Next, you've got some syntax errors.

1. Your array is missing an opening brace.
2. You're searching by ID rather than title.
3. You're not changing a value, you're changing the element's content (you should use `text` or `html`).

So the code should look like:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var monthNames = [ "January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December" ];
  var month = (new Date()).getMonth();
  $("#YourFieldTitle").text(monthNames[month]);
});
```